# Send a select option value to a php script and return the result in a div without refresh

Tags: php, javascript, variables, load

I try to find a solution to this problem but since this is my first time I use javascript I have a big problem.

So here is what I need.

I have 2 drop down list.

Depending on the value selected in the first list the second should show different value value that are extracted from sql and do this without refreshing the page.

The code that extrat those value is a file called getpackage.php and that based on the value retrieved from the first drop list make a query and output the value for the second list.

I have manage to do that by using the .load() function but it only work on firefox, on IE and chrom nothing happen.

Here are the code:

register.php

```
    <select name="product">
                                <?php                       
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM proxy_products";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error, query failed');
            echo "<option value=''></option>";
            while(list($product_id,$product_name) = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
    echo '<option value='".$product_id."' onclick='recp(".$product_id.")' selected >".$product_name."</option>';

            }
    ?>                  
    </select>

//here should the second list load
<select id="showpacakge" name="package">

</select>
```

Java:

```
<script>
function recp(id) {
$('#showpacakge').load('getpackage.php?id='+id);
}
</script>
```

And getpackage.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT package_id, package_name FROM proxy_package WHERE product_id='".$id."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error, query failed');
echo "<option value=''></option>";
    while(list($package_id,$package_name) = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$package_id."' >".$package_name."</option>";
    }
```

As I said this maybe is not so difficult but for me it is because is the first time I try to use java.

And as mentioned it work on firefox but not on IE and Chrome

**UPDATE:**

I got the solution my self.. not sure what exactly is the difference but it work for me

```
<script>
    $("#selectprod").change(function (e)
        {
    var $targ = $(e.target);
    var selected_value = $targ.find('option:selected').val();
    $("#123").load('getpackage.php?id='+ selected_value);
        }
                      )

        .change();
</script>
```

Comment: Two things - you are using javascript not Java (they are very different languages), and also you appear to be using jquery. Suggest you adjust your tags. As for the load method, it works in Chrome and IE - there is something else causing the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using any of the developer tools (e.g. to see if the onclick is working?)  When you say it doesn't work in IE and Chrome, what behavior are you seeing?

Comment: In IE and in Chore the javascritp do nothing.

Comment: Have you done any debugging?  Is the javascript getting called and then failing, or is the javascript not getting triggered via the onClick?